# can't get right value with array

Tags: c++

Q 1.

I want to print the value of even[0] to be 10 with this code below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int odd[10] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
int even[1];
even[0]=(int)odd[0]+(int)odd[9];
cout<<even[0];
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

but I get this output instead.

```
1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Q 2.

But when I change the code to

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int odd[10] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
int even[1];
even[0]=(int)odd[0]+(int)odd[9];
cout<<even;  // No index
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

I get this output.

```
001EFD94
```

Comment: if it is a array of length 10 and you are storing only 5 elements, then `odd[9]` will be a value that makes no sense to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int odd[10] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
```

initialized `odd` to `{1,3,5,7,9,0,0,0,0,0}`, `(int)odd[0]+(int)odd[9]` will get `1`

```
cout<<even;
```

will print address of `even`, you want

```
std::cout<<even[0] << std::endl;
```

§8.5.1.5

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0
> (zero), taken as an integral constant expression, converted to T;103
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each
> non-static data member and each base-class subobject is
> zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) union type, the object’s first
> non-static named data member is zeroinitialized and padding is
> initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
>
> — if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

§8.5.1.7

> 7 To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly
> cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor
> (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the
> initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
> constructor);
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type
> without a user-provided constructor, then the object is
> zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor
> is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
>
> — **if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;**
>
> — **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.**

Answer (score 0):

`odd[9]` is pulling a random chunk of memory, because you didn't initialize the array that far.

Answer (score 0):

The `odd` array has enough room for 10 values, but only the first 5 are initialized explicitly.  The others are implicitly initialized to 0.  So

```
int odd[10] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
```

has the same effect as

```
//     index:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
int odd[10] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

So the line

```
even[0] = (int) odd[0] + (int) odd[9];
```

sets `even[0]` to 1 + 0.  I think you *want*

```
even[0] = odd[0] + odd[4];
```

Note that, since `odd` and `even` are both declared to be of type `int`, you don't need to cast the values before you use them.

When you print `even` without an index, you're printing the *address* of the array, rather than any of its contents.

Comment: i thought when you don't put the index of an array cout prints the array till the null char

Comment: That happens to be true if it's a `char[]` array, because strings are handled differently from numeric arrays.  The name of a `char[]` array is a `char *`, but the name of an `int[]` array is an `int *`.  And `cout` knows to handle them appropriately.

Comment: This is not the case in the question, because `odd` here is not uninitialized, but initialized with less elements, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257828/is-the-rest-element-of-array-initialized-when-no-more-element-in-initialization

Comment: agree with @YuHao on the link, the rest of array is `0` initialized instead of `undefined`

Comment: "The others are undefined and may contain any int value." - others contain zeros, as @YuHao said. "Edited to reflect that" - I don't see.