# Is the rest element of array initialized when no more element in initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the behavior below well-defined?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for(const auto &i: a)
        cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
0
0
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, excess elements are initialized to "zero" (integers to 0, floating-point numbers to 0.0, pointers to `NULL`).

<s>More precisely, the C standard requires that they are initialized as if they had `static` storage duration:</s>

C99 Standard, paragraph 6.7.8.21:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

6.7.8.10:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
>   then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
>
> — if it is a union, the ﬁrst named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>   rules.

Damn, it's C++. (Nobody except @yuan realized this, thanks!)

So paragraph 8.5.1.7 in C++11:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the
>   default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
>   constructor);
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object
>   is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is
>   called.
>
> **— if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;**
>
> **— otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.**

8.5.1.5:

> **To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:**
>
> — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), taken as an integral constant expression,
>   converted to T;
>   103
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class
>   subobject is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) union type, the object’s ﬁrst non-static named data member is zeroinitialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
>
> — if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

Comment: @yuan Chill, I was searching. Ya know the Standard is huge.

Comment: Have you noticed `8.5.1.7` in `n3242`?

Comment: @yuan In fact I haven't noticed that this was C++ and not C.